# How to setup mod_wsgi on a centos 6 server

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have recently completed the development of a django 2 app and part of the requirements is to deploy it to an apache 2 server on a centos machine.
The django app is written with python3 and the centos machine has python2 pre-installed.

So far, I have been having a hard time installing mod_wsgi on the apache2 server and deploying the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have resolved the Issue. See my answer below

Comment: Uninstall the system mod_wsgi package and then use ``pip install`` method to install mod_wsgi. See https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/. If you have further issues, ensure you explain the details of exactly what the problem is else hard to help.

Comment: @Graham . i followed [link](https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi) and was able to find my solution

Answer (score 12):

### 1. Clean install of python 3.6.5 to usr/local and usr/local/lib

I ensured YUM was upto date:

```
$ yum update
```

Compilers and related tools:

```
$ yum groupinstall -y "development tools"
```

libraries needed during compilation to enable all features of Python:

```
$ yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel expat-devel
```

installing Python 3.6.5:

```
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
$ tar xf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
$ cd Python-3.6.5
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
$ make && make altinstall
```

### 2. Installed mod_wsgi using pip install

using the just installed python3.6 i ran the following command

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install mod_wsgi
```

### 3. Load Mod_wsgi into apache module

locate apache config file /etc/apache2/conf/http.conf and add following command to load mod_wsgi by specifying the installation path.
In my case, added the the loadModule command to /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf

```
$ LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

### 4. Restart Apache Server and confirm that mod_wsgi is loaded

```
$ apachectl restart
$ apachectl -M
```

look through the list and ensure that mod_wsgi is part of the modules that is loaded by apache.

#5. configure Virtual host and perform a simple hello.py test
i have a server that is already hosting 7 different sites. i simply created a new subdomain and modified the subdomain virtualhost to look like

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com_ip:80>
    ServerName wsgitest.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.wsgitest.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/account_username/public_html/wsgitest
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com

    <Directory /home/account_username/public_html/wsgitest>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/account_username/public_html/wsgitest/hello.py

    ErrorLog /home/account_username/public_html/wsgitest/wsgitest_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache after modifying the virtualhost

create a `hello.py` wsgi application according to this site - http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

```
# hello.py
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

so my wsgitest application looks like this on the server
`/home/account_username/public_html/wsgitest/hello.py`

Finally, test the site on the browser like so -  wsgitest.mysite.com
you should see  'Hello World'

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Suggest you look at using daemon mode. You would not use embedded mode of mod_wsgi usually.

Comment: I am using the daemon mode. Thanks

Comment: The configuration above doesn't show daemon mode. Does that mean you have changed since? BTW, don't set ``DocumentRoot`` to be where all your code and logs are. If you were to comment out the ``WSGIScriptAlias``, people could download your code. Create an empty ``htdocs`` directory under there and set ``DocumentRoot`` to it.